# Android Service that can last as long as the phone operating with Event Listeners

Tags: android

I have a foreground service that has a thread. This thread implement some event listeners triggered from Internet and sensors.
The App should be always running as far as the phone is on.
What would be the best approach for building this App without draining the battery?
I am looking for best practices for a Service that running all the time listening to Events from Internet and Sensors not a task that should be be finished.

Comment: if you have a service started with `startForeground()` then you are already doing the best approach

Comment: what about the battery drain? for listening to Sensors and Internet.

Comment: What sensors would be listening to? and for what purpose? The reason I'm asking is because some of the very latest phones have much better support for listening to pedometer events and other sensors without using the battery as much, which is something that would drain the battery really quickly on other devices.

Comment: Mostly Accelerometer, and I am listening to it even when the screen is off.

Answer (score 0):

Use a server solution to listen to things on the internet and send your application Google Cloud Messaging push notifications when something happens.

Ideally this way, your service doesn't need to be on all the time waiting for notifications, Android by default already listens for incoming Google Cloud Messaging [push notifications](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) so you wouldn't be adding anything more to the battery drain waiting for such an event.

Android is an event-based system, it does a lot things like that for you to cut down on the need for background services. So instead of having many daemons waiting in the background waiting in a loop, Android has just one system utility that does all of that and that can start your service(s) at the exact right time.

On your side, you just need to register the right [BroadcastReceivers](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) to listen to those events and tell the system what code you want to get triggered when the right combination of incoming events gets triggered.

Comment: I know both. But this is not needed in my case. I use XMPP for backend.